# Multiple if statements in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm doing the first project euler problem and I just did this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int threes =0;
int fives = 0;
int both = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      
       if(i%3==0){
   threes += i;
   }
  
       if(i%5==0){
   fives += i;
   }
   
      if ( i % 5 == 0 && i % 3 == 0){
      both += i;
  }

}

cout << "threes = " << threes << endl;
cout << "fives = " << fives << endl;
cout << "both = " << both << endl;

cout << " threes + fives - both = " << endl;
int result = (threes + fives) - both;
cout << result<< endl;

return 0;
}
```

My professor recently corrected me for doing this in a different problem saying something about `else` statements,
but I don't understand WHY i have to add `else` in front of the next `if`. for what its worth I have another version with `else if(i%5){ fives += .... }`
and they both work and get me the right answer.

My question is whats inherently wrong with this way of thinking, is it stylistic or am I not thinking logically about something?

If it works, why use switch statements ever?

Comment: Based on the question: I bet that you are not supposed to increment `both` if you also increment `three` and `five`. i.e. each time through the loop only one variable needs to be incremented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `else` branch in an `if-else` statement is only executed if the `if` branch is `false`. If you just have two `if` statements in a row, they'll both be executed, which can be a waste. In the below code, the `else` prevents the second computation from running if the first is satisfied.

```
if (expensive_computation1()) {
  ...
}
else if (expensive_computation2()) {
  ...
}
```

Additionally, it's clearer to humans reading the code whether both `if` statements should be allowed to run or whether only one should.

Answer (score 5):

The only thing that I see wrong with your implementation is that in the case where the number is both a multiple of 3 and a multiple of 5 not only is the both variable incremented but the fives and threes variables are also incremented.  Based on what the professor described I believe he wants you to use an else-if so that the both variable is the only one that is incremented when you pass in a number that is both a multiple of 3 and a multiple of 5.

The reason you get the correct answer both ways is because you are only going to 10 in the for loop, if you increase it to i <= 15 you will get fives and threes being 1 higher than I think he intended.

For example:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
   if( ( ( i % 3 ) == 0 ) && ( ( i % 5 ) == 0 ) )
   {
      both++;
   }
   else if( ( i % 3 ) == 0 )
   {
      threes++;
   }
   else if( ( i % 5 ) == 0 )
   {
      fives++;
   }
}
```

Comment: the professor comment I made was for a different problem. I actually don't need the both variable at all. 
My final implementation is 

if ( i % 3 == 0 ){
    threes += i ;
}
else if ( i % 5  == 0 ) {
    fives += i;
}

I don't need both because a number like 15 will be true for the 3 part and thus skip the 5 statement, so all numbers are only being counted once. its weird cause I've had three ideas/implementations and they've all given me the correct answer...

Answer (score 2):

In this case, maybe you really want this:

```
if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 3 == 0) {
    both += i;
} else if (i % 3 == 0) {
    threes += i;  
} else if (i % 5 == 0) {
    fives += i;
}
```

(why you do `+= i` instead of `++` I don't know but you didn't explain, so I just copied it)

In your code, `threes` and `fives` were incremented *even if* it would also increase `both`, which depending on your problem may not be what you want. If you do the if/else way I've just presented, only one of the three variables is increased.

Comment: the original question was, "Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000". I want to add the numbers up not keep track of how many there are, which is why  did += . I actually got rid of the both idea. didn't need it.  thanks though, everyones answer has helped

Answer (score 1):

***Why use `if-else` instead of multiple `if's`?***
`if-else` & `if` would achieve the same results but `if-else` achieves them in a performance enhanced way. with multiple `if's` every if condition will have to be checked. With `if-else` only one conditional check will have to be performed and the rest of the conditions just don't need to be checked at all.

This would not affect a small program like the one you have but it will sure have some impact in potentially expensive function being called repeatedly over and over again.

***If it works, why use switch statements ever?***
With nested `if-else` conditions the code is hard to read and understand. The `switch-case` construct helps to represent the conditions in a much easier to read & understand format.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like stylistics. You can use some autoreformating tool that follows certain established stylistic look (K&R, ANSI, GNU, etc.)

For example astyle is such tool, http://astyle.sourceforge.net/ - just reformat your code with it, and you might have a happy professor.